# how to know the reason of Back-off restarting failed container of elasticsearch

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes

I am deploy elasticsearch in my kubernetes cluster using this command follow this [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-quickstart.html):

```
kubectl apply -f https://download.elastic.co/downloads/eck/1.0.1/all-in-one.yaml
```

create service:

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: quickstart
spec:
  version: 7.6.0
  nodeSets:
  - name: default
    count: 1
    config:
      node.master: true
      node.data: true
      node.ingest: true
      node.store.allow_mmap: false
```

now all service start success except the pods `quickstart-es-default-0`.It shows `Back-off restarting failed container`. Check the log output:

```
~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Document/k8s/work/skywalking ⌚ 10:02:01
$ kubectl logs quickstart-es-default-0
Error from server (BadRequest): container "elasticsearch" in pod "quickstart-es-default-0" is waiting to start: PodInitializing
```

I could get any useful message from the log output.Now I want to know why could this happen,how to fix it?

I have tried:

- retart pods
- free host memory > 4GB

I found some failed state from kubernetes dashboard but still do not know how to fix it:

[image]

PS:this is my Stateful Sets yaml:

```
{
  "kind": "StatefulSet",
  "apiVersion": "apps/v1beta2",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "quickstart-es-default",
    "namespace": "dabai-fat",
    "selfLink": "/apis/apps/v1beta2/namespaces/dabai-fat/statefulsets/quickstart-es-default",
    "uid": "430b0f0d-a771-4ad5-8eaa-963e5646d508",
    "resourceVersion": "16783276",
    "generation": 9,
    "creationTimestamp": "2020-02-27T04:39:27Z",
    "labels": {
      "common.k8s.elastic.co/template-hash": "1894377832",
      "common.k8s.elastic.co/type": "elasticsearch",
      "elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/cluster-name": "quickstart",
      "elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/statefulset-name": "quickstart-es-default"
    },
    "ownerReferences": [
      {
        "apiVersion": "elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1",
        "kind": "Elasticsearch",
        "name": "quickstart",
        "uid": "3b2483cb-6da2-418f-8e9d-5a3059720d7a",
        "controller": true,
        "blockOwnerDeletion": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 1,
    "selector": {
      "matchLabels": {
        "common.k8s.elastic.co/type": "elasticsearch",
        "elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/cluster-name": "quickstart",
        "elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/statefulset-name": "quickstart-es-default"
      }
    },
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": null,
        "labels": {
          "common.k8s.elastic.co/type": "elasticsearch",
          "elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/cluster-name": "quickstart",
          "elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/config-hash": "2034778696",
          "elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/http-scheme": "https",
          "elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/node-data": "true",
          "elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/node-ingest": "true",
          "elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/node-master": "true",
          "elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/node-ml": "true",
          "elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/statefulset-name": "quickstart-es-default",
          "elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/version": "7.6.0"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "volumes": [
          {
            "name": "downward-api",
            "downwardAPI": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "path": "labels",
                  "fieldRef": {
                    "apiVersion": "v1",
                    "fieldPath": "metadata.labels"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "defaultMode": 420
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "elastic-internal-elasticsearch-bin-local",
            "emptyDir": {}
          },
          {
            "name": "elastic-internal-elasticsearch-config",
            "secret": {
              "secretName": "quickstart-es-default-es-config",
              "defaultMode": 420,
              "optional": false
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "elastic-internal-elasticsearch-config-local",
            "emptyDir": {}
          },
          {
            "name": "elastic-internal-elasticsearch-plugins-local",
            "emptyDir": {}
          },
          {
            "name": "elastic-internal-http-certificates",
            "secret": {
              "secretName": "quickstart-es-http-certs-internal",
              "defaultMode": 420,
              "optional": false
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "elastic-internal-probe-user",
            "secret": {
              "secretName": "quickstart-es-internal-users",
              "items": [
                {
                  "key": "elastic-internal-probe",
                  "path": "elastic-internal-probe"
                }
              ],
              "defaultMode": 420,
              "optional": false
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "elastic-internal-scripts",
            "configMap": {
              "name": "quickstart-es-scripts",
              "defaultMode": 493,
              "optional": false
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "elastic-internal-transport-certificates",
            "secret": {
              "secretName": "quickstart-es-transport-certificates",
              "defaultMode": 420,
              "optional": false
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "elastic-internal-unicast-hosts",
            "configMap": {
              "name": "quickstart-es-unicast-hosts",
              "defaultMode": 420,
              "optional": false
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "elastic-internal-xpack-file-realm",
            "secret": {
              "secretName": "quickstart-es-xpack-file-realm",
              "defaultMode": 420,
              "optional": false
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "elasticsearch-data",
            "persistentVolumeClaim": {
              "claimName": "claim-name-placeholder"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "elasticsearch-logs",
            "emptyDir": {}
          }
        ],
        "initContainers": [
          {
            "name": "elastic-internal-init-filesystem",
            "image": "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.0",
            "command": [
              "bash",
              "-c",
              "/mnt/elastic-internal/scripts/prepare-fs.sh"
            ],
            "env": [
              {
                "name": "POD_IP",
                "valueFrom": {
                  "fieldRef": {
                    "apiVersion": "v1",
                    "fieldPath": "status.podIP"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "POD_NAME",
                "valueFrom": {
                  "fieldRef": {
                    "apiVersion": "v1",
                    "fieldPath": "metadata.name"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "POD_IP",
                "valueFrom": {
                  "fieldRef": {
                    "apiVersion": "v1",
                    "fieldPath": "status.podIP"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "POD_NAME",
                "valueFrom": {
                  "fieldRef": {
                    "apiVersion": "v1",
                    "fieldPath": "metadata.name"
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "resources": {
              "limits": {
                "cpu": "100m",
                "memory": "50Mi"
              },
              "requests": {
                "cpu": "100m",
                "memory": "50Mi"
              }
            },
            "volumeMounts": [
              {
                "name": "elastic-internal-elasticsearch-config-local",
                "mountPath": "/mnt/elastic-internal/elasticsearch-config-local"
              },
              {
                "name": "elastic-internal-elasticsearch-plugins-local",
                "mountPath": "/mnt/elastic-internal/elasticsearch-plugins-local"
              },
              {
                "name": "elastic-internal-elasticsearch-bin-local",
                "mountPath": "/mnt/elastic-internal/elasticsearch-bin-local"
              },
              {
                "name": "elastic-internal-transport-certificates",
                "readOnly": true,
                "mountPath": "/mnt/elastic-internal/transport-certificates"
              },
              {
                "name": "elastic-internal-scripts",
                "readOnly": true,
                "mountPath": "/mnt/elastic-internal/scripts"
              },
              {
                "name": "elasticsearch-data",
                "mountPath": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
              },
              {
                "name": "elasticsearch-logs",
                "mountPath": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs"
              },
              {
                "name": "downward-api",
                "readOnly": true,
                "mountPath": "/mnt/elastic-internal/downward-api"
              },
              {
                "name": "elastic-internal-elasticsearch-config",
                "readOnly": true,
                "mountPath": "/mnt/elastic-internal/elasticsearch-config"
              },
              {
                "name": "elastic-internal-http-certificates",
                "readOnly": true,
                "mountPath": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/http-certs"
              },
              {
                "name": "elastic-internal-probe-user",
                "readOnly": true,
                "mountPath": "/mnt/elastic-internal/probe-user"
              },
              {
                "name": "elastic-internal-unicast-hosts",
                "readOnly": true,
                "mountPath": "/mnt/elastic-internal/unicast-hosts"
              },
              {
                "name": "elastic-internal-xpack-file-realm",
                "readOnly": true,
                "mountPath": "/mnt/elastic-internal/xpack-file-realm"
              }
            ],
            "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
            "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
            "securityContext": {
              "privileged": false
            }
          }
        ],
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "elasticsearch",
            "image": "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.0",
            "ports": [
              {
                "name": "http",
                "containerPort": 9200,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              },
              {
                "name": "transport",
                "containerPort": 9300,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              }
            ],
            "env": [
              {
                "name": "HEADLESS_SERVICE_NAME",
                "value": "quickstart-es-default"
              },
              {
                "name": "NSS_SDB_USE_CACHE",
                "value": "no"
              },
              {
                "name": "POD_IP",
                "valueFrom": {
                  "fieldRef": {
                    "apiVersion": "v1",
                    "fieldPath": "status.podIP"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "POD_NAME",
                "valueFrom": {
                  "fieldRef": {
                    "apiVersion": "v1",
                    "fieldPath": "metadata.name"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "PROBE_PASSWORD_PATH",
                "value": "/mnt/elastic-internal/probe-user/elastic-internal-probe"
              },
              {
                "name": "PROBE_USERNAME",
                "value": "elastic-internal-probe"
              },
              {
                "name": "READINESS_PROBE_PROTOCOL",
                "value": "https"
              }
            ],
            "resources": {
              "limits": {
                "memory": "2Gi"
              },
              "requests": {
                "memory": "2Gi"
              }
            },
            "volumeMounts": [
              {
                "name": "downward-api",
                "readOnly": true,
                "mountPath": "/mnt/elastic-internal/downward-api"
              },
              {
                "name": "elastic-internal-elasticsearch-bin-local",
                "mountPath": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin"
              },
              {
                "name": "elastic-internal-elasticsearch-config",
                "readOnly": true,
                "mountPath": "/mnt/elastic-internal/elasticsearch-config"
              },
              {
                "name": "elastic-internal-elasticsearch-config-local",
                "mountPath": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config"
              },
              {
                "name": "elastic-internal-elasticsearch-plugins-local",
                "mountPath": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins"
              },
              {
                "name": "elastic-internal-http-certificates",
                "readOnly": true,
                "mountPath": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/http-certs"
              },
              {
                "name": "elastic-internal-probe-user",
                "readOnly": true,
                "mountPath": "/mnt/elastic-internal/probe-user"
              },
              {
                "name": "elastic-internal-scripts",
                "readOnly": true,
                "mountPath": "/mnt/elastic-internal/scripts"
              },
              {
                "name": "elastic-internal-transport-certificates",
                "readOnly": true,
                "mountPath": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/transport-certs"
              },
              {
                "name": "elastic-internal-unicast-hosts",
                "readOnly": true,
                "mountPath": "/mnt/elastic-internal/unicast-hosts"
              },
              {
                "name": "elastic-internal-xpack-file-realm",
                "readOnly": true,
                "mountPath": "/mnt/elastic-internal/xpack-file-realm"
              },
              {
                "name": "elasticsearch-data",
                "mountPath": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
              },
              {
                "name": "elasticsearch-logs",
                "mountPath": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs"
              }
            ],
            "readinessProbe": {
              "exec": {
                "command": [
                  "bash",
                  "-c",
                  "/mnt/elastic-internal/scripts/readiness-probe-script.sh"
                ]
              },
              "initialDelaySeconds": 10,
              "timeoutSeconds": 5,
              "periodSeconds": 5,
              "successThreshold": 1,
              "failureThreshold": 3
            },
            "lifecycle": {
              "preStop": {
                "exec": {
                  "command": [
                    "bash",
                    "-c",
                    "/mnt/elastic-internal/scripts/pre-stop-hook-script.sh"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
            "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent"
          }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Always",
        "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 180,
        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
        "automountServiceAccountToken": false,
        "securityContext": {},
        "affinity": {
          "podAntiAffinity": {
            "preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution": [
              {
                "weight": 100,
                "podAffinityTerm": {
                  "labelSelector": {
                    "matchLabels": {
                      "elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/cluster-name": "quickstart"
                    }
                  },
                  "topologyKey": "kubernetes.io/hostname"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "schedulerName": "default-scheduler"
      }
    },
    "volumeClaimTemplates": [
      {
        "metadata": {
          "name": "elasticsearch-data",
          "creationTimestamp": null,
          "ownerReferences": [
            {
              "apiVersion": "elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1",
              "kind": "Elasticsearch",
              "name": "quickstart",
              "uid": "3b2483cb-6da2-418f-8e9d-5a3059720d7a",
              "controller": true,
              "blockOwnerDeletion": false
            }
          ]
        },
        "spec": {
          "accessModes": [
            "ReadWriteOnce"
          ],
          "resources": {
            "requests": {
              "storage": "1Gi"
            }
          },
          "volumeMode": "Filesystem"
        },
        "status": {
          "phase": "Pending"
        }
      }
    ],
    "serviceName": "quickstart-es-default",
    "podManagementPolicy": "Parallel",
    "updateStrategy": {
      "type": "OnDelete"
    },
    "revisionHistoryLimit": 10
  },
  "status": {
    "observedGeneration": 9,
    "replicas": 1,
    "currentReplicas": 1,
    "updatedReplicas": 1,
    "currentRevision": "quickstart-es-default-7c6864f4c",
    "updateRevision": "quickstart-es-default-7c6864f4c",
    "collisionCount": 0
  }
}
```

This is the events output(by the way,Now I moved all service into `elastic-system` namespace):

[image]

This is the stateful set describe output:

```
$ kubectl describe statefulset quickstart-es-default
Name:               quickstart-es-default
Namespace:          elastic-system
CreationTimestamp:  Thu, 27 Feb 2020 13:57:05 +0800
Selector:           common.k8s.elastic.co/type=elasticsearch,elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/cluster-name=quickstart,elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/statefulset-name=quickstart-es-default
Labels:             common.k8s.elastic.co/template-hash=617547124
                    common.k8s.elastic.co/type=elasticsearch
                    elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/cluster-name=quickstart
                    elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/statefulset-name=quickstart-es-default
Annotations:        <none>
Replicas:           1 desired | 1 total
Update Strategy:    OnDelete
Pods Status:        0 Running / 1 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:  common.k8s.elastic.co/type=elasticsearch
           elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/cluster-name=quickstart
           elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/config-hash=2034778696
           elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/http-scheme=https
           elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/node-data=true
           elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/node-ingest=true
           elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/node-master=true
           elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/node-ml=true
           elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/statefulset-name=quickstart-es-default
           elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/version=7.6.0
  Init Containers:
   elastic-internal-init-filesystem:
    Image:      docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.0
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Command:
      bash
      -c
      /mnt/elastic-internal/scripts/prepare-fs.sh
    Limits:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  50Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  50Mi
    Environment:
      POD_IP:     (v1:status.podIP)
      POD_NAME:   (v1:metadata.name)
      POD_IP:     (v1:status.podIP)
      POD_NAME:   (v1:metadata.name)
    Mounts:
      /mnt/elastic-internal/downward-api from downward-api (ro)
      /mnt/elastic-internal/elasticsearch-bin-local from elastic-internal-elasticsearch-bin-local (rw)
      /mnt/elastic-internal/elasticsearch-config from elastic-internal-elasticsearch-config (ro)
      /mnt/elastic-internal/elasticsearch-config-local from elastic-internal-elasticsearch-config-local (rw)
      /mnt/elastic-internal/elasticsearch-plugins-local from elastic-internal-elasticsearch-plugins-local (rw)
      /mnt/elastic-internal/probe-user from elastic-internal-probe-user (ro)
      /mnt/elastic-internal/scripts from elastic-internal-scripts (ro)
      /mnt/elastic-internal/transport-certificates from elastic-internal-transport-certificates (ro)
      /mnt/elastic-internal/unicast-hosts from elastic-internal-unicast-hosts (ro)
      /mnt/elastic-internal/xpack-file-realm from elastic-internal-xpack-file-realm (ro)
      /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/http-certs from elastic-internal-http-certificates (ro)
      /usr/share/elasticsearch/data from elasticsearch-data (rw)
      /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs from elasticsearch-logs (rw)
  Containers:
   elasticsearch:
    Image:       docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.0
    Ports:       9200/TCP, 9300/TCP
    Host Ports:  0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Limits:
      memory:  2Gi
    Requests:
      memory:   2Gi
    Readiness:  exec [bash -c /mnt/elastic-internal/scripts/readiness-probe-script.sh] delay=10s timeout=5s period=5s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      HEADLESS_SERVICE_NAME:     quickstart-es-default
      NSS_SDB_USE_CACHE:         no
      POD_IP:                     (v1:status.podIP)
      POD_NAME:                   (v1:metadata.name)
      PROBE_PASSWORD_PATH:       /mnt/elastic-internal/probe-user/elastic-internal-probe
      PROBE_USERNAME:            elastic-internal-probe
      READINESS_PROBE_PROTOCOL:  https
    Mounts:
      /mnt/elastic-internal/downward-api from downward-api (ro)
      /mnt/elastic-internal/elasticsearch-config from elastic-internal-elasticsearch-config (ro)
      /mnt/elastic-internal/probe-user from elastic-internal-probe-user (ro)
      /mnt/elastic-internal/scripts from elastic-internal-scripts (ro)
      /mnt/elastic-internal/unicast-hosts from elastic-internal-unicast-hosts (ro)
      /mnt/elastic-internal/xpack-file-realm from elastic-internal-xpack-file-realm (ro)
      /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin from elastic-internal-elasticsearch-bin-local (rw)
      /usr/share/elasticsearch/config from elastic-internal-elasticsearch-config-local (rw)
      /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/http-certs from elastic-internal-http-certificates (ro)
      /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/transport-certs from elastic-internal-transport-certificates (ro)
      /usr/share/elasticsearch/data from elasticsearch-data (rw)
      /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs from elasticsearch-logs (rw)
      /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins from elastic-internal-elasticsearch-plugins-local (rw)
  Volumes:
   downward-api:
    Type:  DownwardAPI (a volume populated by information about the pod)
    Items:
      metadata.labels -> labels
   elastic-internal-elasticsearch-bin-local:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
   elastic-internal-elasticsearch-config:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  quickstart-es-default-es-config
    Optional:    false
   elastic-internal-elasticsearch-config-local:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
   elastic-internal-elasticsearch-plugins-local:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
   elastic-internal-http-certificates:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  quickstart-es-http-certs-internal
    Optional:    false
   elastic-internal-probe-user:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  quickstart-es-internal-users
    Optional:    false
   elastic-internal-scripts:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      quickstart-es-scripts
    Optional:  false
   elastic-internal-transport-certificates:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  quickstart-es-transport-certificates
    Optional:    false
   elastic-internal-unicast-hosts:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      quickstart-es-unicast-hosts
    Optional:  false
   elastic-internal-xpack-file-realm:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  quickstart-es-xpack-file-realm
    Optional:    false
   elasticsearch-data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  claim-name-placeholder
    ReadOnly:   false
   elasticsearch-logs:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
Volume Claims:
  Name:          elasticsearch-data
  StorageClass:
  Labels:        <none>
  Annotations:   <none>
  Capacity:      1Gi
  Access Modes:  [ReadWriteOnce]
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age                From                    Message
  ----    ------            ----               ----                    -------
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  58m                statefulset-controller  create Claim elasticsearch-data-quickstart-es-default-0 Pod quickstart-es-default-0 in StatefulSet quickstart-es-default success
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  35m                statefulset-controller  create Claim elasticsearch-data-quickstart-es-default-1 Pod quickstart-es-default-1 in StatefulSet quickstart-es-default success
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  35m                statefulset-controller  create Pod quickstart-es-default-1 in StatefulSet quickstart-es-default successful
  Normal  SuccessfulDelete  30m (x3 over 47m)  statefulset-controller  delete Pod quickstart-es-default-0 in StatefulSet quickstart-es-default successful
  Normal  SuccessfulDelete  30m                statefulset-controller  delete Pod quickstart-es-default-1 in StatefulSet quickstart-es-default successful
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  30m (x4 over 58m)  statefulset-controller  create Pod quickstart-es-default-0 in StatefulSet quickstart-es-default successful
```

Comment: what is the output of kubectl get events?

Comment: Can you use `kubectl describe` for both statefulset and pod? Attach the result to the question body.

Comment: If it's in `CrashLoopBockOff` state then the output of `kubectl logs` is going to be the most interesting thing.  Screen shots of the Kubernetes dashboard aren't especially useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the init container `elastic-internal-init-filesystem` is not running. 
Check logs of init container `kubectl logs <pod-name> -c elastic-internal-init-filesystem`

The recommended [debugging steps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-init-containers/) of init container.

Comment: I found this output:  `chowning /usr/share/elasticsearch/data to elasticsearch:elasticsearch
chown: changing ownership of '/usr/share/elasticsearch/data': Operation not permitted
failed to change ownership of '/usr/share/elasticsearch/data' from root:root to elasticsearch:elasticsearch`

Comment: Worth asking a different question